# getting Error: shuffle(...) is undefined in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined

Doesn't matter when I put it in the app.js file it keeps getting undefined..

app.js

```
(function () {
var tkcApp = angular.module('TKC', []);

var shuffle = function (o) {
for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i),
    x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
};
tkcApp.controller('ShuffleCtrl', function ($scope) {
var quotes = [
"Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, it can achieve. –Napoleon Hill",
"You miss 100% of the shots you don’t take. –Wayne Gretzky",
];

$scope.getQuote = function () {
  $scope.array = shuffle(quotes).slice(0, 1);
  };
$scope.getQuote();
})
})();
```

view

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-controller="ShuffleCtrl" onload="getQuote()">
     <p ng-repeat="value in array">{{ value }}</p>
 </div>
```

I've put outside the controller as the example I got this from showed, and tried using it as $scope.shuffle, but I just doesn't work. And yes I have body ng-app="TKC"

Comment: what is with the comma after the for loop?

Comment: `shuffle` function doesn't have `return o` or something like that, yet you attempt to slice its result. And `undefined` doesn't like to get sliced. )

Comment: @epascarello No, that's actually a *highly enhanced shuffle*.

Comment: @raina77ow post the answer... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `shuffle` function you use in your code operates 'in-place' - it affects the array sent in it as its param, returning nothing. Yet you attempt to use its result immediately.

So either add `return o` into `shuffle` code, or change the using code like that:

```
shuffle(quotes);
$scope.array = quotes.slice(0, 1);
```

Comment: thanks for the input, just posted a answer with, almost, that conclusion. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

i found out the answer from a co-worker. $scope.array gets empty since shuffle doesn't return a value, so putting 'return o' at the bottom fixed the issue.